# Include search by tag in catalog search

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, tags

I need to include search by **product tags** in the default catalog search in magento,
I thought of **hooking the catalog search with any event** related to it, but could not find any event where i can detect if the search keyword is a tag or not,Is there any event for that? or do i need to rewrite the classes?
**System Configurations -> Catalog->Catalog Search**, i have selected fulltext as Search type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to Combine and its searching by tags

Comment: Dont work for me :(